# how to access a binary file randomly jumping to a constant position

Tags: java

I was making a small dictionary with java. my problem is I can’t access a word in a binary file randomly. Meaning for example if I have the words:

play

- pronunciation: // something
- type: verb
- meaning :- to have fun doing something'

manipulation

- pronunciation:// something
- type:// something
- meaning :- // some meaning

kill

- pronunciation: // something
- type:// something
- meaning :- // some meaning

The word manipulation will occupy more byte than the other two. What I want to do is the program to read play get its position and jump the three lines pronunciation, type and meaning and go read manipulation and get its position so I can access it later.
But I could because all words have different bytes help!

```
public class BinaryIO { 
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        String file_name = "person.bin";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileO = new FileOutputStream(new File("person.bin"));
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(fileO);
            person teddy = new person();
            teddy.name= "x";
            teddy.address= " somwhere";
            teddy.phone= " 484892";
            out.writeObject(teddy);
            out.close();
            fileO.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" out failed");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("reading :");

        try {
            FileInputStream fileI = new FileInputStream(new File("ArtistName.bin"));
            RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile(file_name, "r");

            in.seek(12);
            long len = in.length();
            String str = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(str);

            str = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(str);

            System.out.println("length:  " + len + "\n");
            in.close();
        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(" in failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you choose a binary format?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should just use a well-known data exchange format (e.g. JSON, XML, pick your poison), and the entire problem would be trivial then.

Comment: What's your actual question? You have a code dump and some requirements. What's actually wrong with the code dump? What do you want to fix? We aren't going to design a system and write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make a defined `char` array for every entry and arbitrarily jump to the beginning of the input, in my case was after 127 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a binary file is absolutely mandated, I'd go with a text file where individual word attributes are placed on new lines. I'd read the entries for each word into a new Person object and place that Person object in a hash table using the word in question as the key to the hash table.

The code would look something like this:

```
Hashtable<String, Person> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, Person>();
String Word, Pronounciation, Type, Meaning, RequiredWord;
Person RequiredObj;

try
{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
    while(br.ready())
    {
        Word = br.readLine();
        Pronunciation = br.readLine();
        Type = br.readLine();
        Meaning = br.readLine();

        if (Word != null && Pronunciation != null &&
            Type != null && Meaning != null)
        {
            // Note: Make the Person object immutable and initialize all attributes
            // in the constructor.
            hashtable.put(Word, new Person(Word, Pronunciation, Type, Meaning));
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    br.close();

}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}        

// Get a Person object from the hash table.
RequiredObj = hashtable.get(RequiredWord);
```

If a binary file must be used, then you'll need to create a lookup table at the top of the file listing each word in the file and its corresponding byte offset from the start of the file. The attributes of each word would need to be demarcated with some kind of marker or, alternatively, each attribute could start with an integer that says how many bytes the attribute takes up. This implementation however is very messy and would be slow if quick access to word definitions were required. Hash tables, in comparison, are super fast.

Comment: Why invent your own file format? Pick JSON, YAML, heck even XML, and use an existing library for parsing.

Comment: @Robert - Judging by the questions in Bereket's profile, he's most likely doing a Java course and this is an assignment question.

Comment: @hermit if so, then we are probably the wrong people to answer this question - IMVHO the person who gave the assignment/who maintains the course is.

Comment: Why dont you guys just say we didn't/dont know the answer.